# Application.instanceInitializer is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ember.js Application example</title>
  <!-- CDN's -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Your JavaScript -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
                     <!-- this is default application template -->
                      <h1>{{App.name}}</h1>
                      {{outlet}}
                  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //App is the object of the Ember.Application
    //create() is the constructor of the Ember.Application
    App = Ember.Application.create();
    //App.name is the variable that holds the string values
    App.name= "Hello... Welcome to TutorialsPoint";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran this.But `Application.instanceInitializer` is not a function in `ember-initializer.js` how solve this error?

Comment: 1.10.0 is an older version of Ember. Any reason you're using that?

Answer (score 0):

You are including a version of Ember Data that is incompatible with the version of Ember you are using.

Quick fix:

Swap this:

```
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
```

For this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.13.15/ember-data.js"></script>
```

And the error will disappear and the app will do what it should.

What might be better is to find a more up-to-date tutorial and follow that.